# Problemas para criar SpringBoot

Tags: java

estou com problemas ao tentar transformar minha aplicação em uma API usando SpringBoot.
Segui vários tutoriais na WEB. No entanto, alguns problemas de dependências persistem.
Meu programa tem o intuito de transformar imagens em caracteres (o famoso OCR). Usei o Tesseract em java (tess4j.jar).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
C:\api>mvnw spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------------< com.lpr:api >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ api >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] The encoding used to copy filtered properties files have not been set. This means that the same encoding will be used to copy filtered properties files as when copying other filtered resources. This might not be what you want! Run your build with --debug to see which files might be affected. Read more at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filtering-properties-files.html
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ api ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\api\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ api ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ api <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) @ api ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/TurboFilter
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem$Factory.getLoggingSystem(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:348)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.getLoggingSystem(DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.java:44)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:231)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:213)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$starting$0(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
        at com.lpr.api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.TurboFilter
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 18 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.475 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-13T14:38:24-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:run (default-cli) on project api: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lpr</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <description>Microserviço do LPR</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0-3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: essa classe TurboFilter está no seu projeto? (procure sempre colar o texto e não uma imagem, assim fica mais fácil de ler e de buscar)

Comment: essa classe turboFilter não está no projeto

Comment: TurboFilter é uma classe do logback, conforme mostra na stack do erro... Fica dificil advinhar o problema sem saber como esta a configuração do seu projeto. Mostre o seu `pom.xml`

Comment: Entendo. Meu arquivo pom.xml

Comment: Como esta seu `application.yml`? Você esta tentando utilizar o `logback` como logging provider?
Se for o caso, de uma olhada nessa [questão do stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894774/spring-boot-noclassdeffounderror-ch-qos-logback-classic-level/47895025).
A pessoa passa pelo mesmo problema, resumindo você precisa incluir no seu pom as dependências do logback em si, o SpringBoot não contém ela por default.

Answer (score 0):

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.4.1
 

com.lpr
api
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
api
Microserviço do LPR

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0-3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Você deve editar a própria pergunta para adicionar novos dados, vc utiliza da resposta caso tenha encontrado a resposta para a própria pergunta.